# Fill NAs in a Column with samples from itself

Tags: python, pandas

Simple toy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol':['foo','bar','hello','there',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'foo'],
                  'mycol2':'this is here to make it a DF'.split()})
print(df)

   mycol mycol2
0    foo   this
1    bar     is
2  hello   here
3  there     to
4    NaN   make
5    NaN     it
6    NaN      a
7    foo     DF
```

I'm trying to fill the NaNs in `mycol` with samples from itself, e.g. I want the NaNs to be replaced with samples of `foo`,`bar`,`hello` etc.

```
# fill NA values with n samples (n= number of NAs) from df['mycol']

df['mycol'].fillna(df['mycol'].sample(n=df.isna().sum(), random_state=1,replace=True).values)

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

```
# fill NA values with n samples, n=1. Dropna from df['mycol'] before sampling:

df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].fillna(df['mycol'].dropna().sample(n=1, random_state=1,replace=True)).values

# nothing happens
```

Expected Output: Nas filled with random samples from `mycol`:

```
   mycol mycol2
0    foo   this
1    bar     is
2  hello   here
3  there     to
4    foo   make
5    foo     it
6  hello      a
7    foo     DF
```

*edit for answer:* @Jezrael's answer below sorted it, I had a problem with my indexes.

```
df['mycol'] = (df['mycol'] 
               .dropna()
               .sample(n=len(df),replace=True) 
               .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: `n = df.isna().sum()` this part is the problem; check it and you'll see that it gives two numbers instead of one

Comment: can you add expected output in your question?

Comment: @Asif added to original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem.

For me working set values with `loc` with converting values to numpy array for avoid data alignment:

```
a = df['mycol'].dropna().sample(n=df['mycol'].isna().sum(), random_state=1,replace=True)
print (a)
3    there
7      foo
0      foo
Name: mycol, dtype: object

#pandas 0.24+
df.loc[df['mycol'].isna(), 'mycol'] = a.to_numpy()
#pandas below
#df.loc[df['mycol'].isna(), 'mycol'] = a.values
print (df)
   mycol mycol2
0    foo   this
1    bar     is
2  hello   here
3  there     to
4  there   make
5    foo     it
6    foo      a
7    foo     DF
```

Your solution should working if length of Series and index same like original `DataFrame`:

```
s = df['mycol'].dropna().sample(n=len(df), random_state=1,replace=True)
s.index = df.index
print (s)
0    there
1      foo
2      foo
3      bar
4    there
5      foo
6      foo
7      bar
Name: mycol, dtype: object

df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].fillna(s)
print (df)

#   mycol mycol2
0    foo   this
1    bar     is
2  hello   here
3  there     to
4  there   make
5    foo     it
6    foo      a
7    foo     DF
```

Comment: This variation of your one works too I think: `df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].dropna().sample(n=len(df), random_state=1,replace=True).reset_index(drop=True)` ... one liner but looks a bit messy

Answer (score 1):

you can do forward or backward fill:

```
#backward fill
df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].fillna(method='bfill')

#forward Fill
df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].fillna(method='ffill')
```